One user cannot create subscription inside topic in Azure Service Bus (JavaScript)
One user of my aplication that should create subscription in a specific topic is unable to do so (all of the others can). User is getting error with the following content:
<Error>
<Code>400</Code>
<Detail>The specified resource description is invalid.
 TrackingId:1e75e58c-e002-4092-b9e5-2d00c702d785_G12, 
 SystemTracker:*name of my service bus*:Topic:*name of my topic*, 
 Timestamp:2024-08-16T08:05:54
</Detail>
</Error>

The code that is working successfully for everybody else but for this user is the following:
this._sbAdminClient.createSubscription(
                        `myApp-${user}`, 
                        azureSubscriptionId,
                        {
                            autoDeleteOnIdle: 'PT1H',
                        }
                    )
// {user} variable here is just a simple string and it does contain only simple latin characters

Just to be clear, if I check Azure portal, the topic exists and if I manually create subscription, then receiver works fine.
EDIT on 03.09.2024
My team actually discovered that this is happening only in Mozilla Firefox. The reason is that the .createSubscription method in Chrome for example is sending in PUT payload the following XML which corresponds with official schema:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <content type="application/xml">
        <SubscriptionDescription
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect">
            <AutoDeleteOnIdle>PT1H</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
        </SubscriptionDescription>
    </content>
</entry>

But in Mozilla (version 115) the sent XML looks like this:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry>
    <updated>2024-08-28T09:36:15.430Z</updated>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <SubscriptionDescription
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoDeleteOnIdle>PT1H</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
        </SubscriptionDescription>
    </content>
</entry>

The URL is the same for both of these calls: https://ibit-lazarus-dev.servicebus.windows.net/{name of the subscription to be created}/Subscriptions/66d6bf8b925a793953574ac8?api-version=2021-05

I'm assuming that the subscription that you are manually creating through the portal has the same name as myApp-${user}? Otherwise, what happens if you try naming it the same?
Have you checked that the character encoding of user is the same for everybody? Has the user tried creating a subscription with a name that does not contain the user variable?
Also, maybe add some more details about the user variable. Does it contain any special characters, what's its length, etc?
Can the user create other service bus entities through the Admin client?

Hi Isak. Thanks for your coment. User is just a simple string variable with regular latin characters. I checked with user. He was able to create subscription manualy through the portal

I'd still check the char encoding and compare it to that of your other users, and copy the username directly from an application log and check it for hidden characters. Otherwise I have no clue why it wouldn't work.

What packages and versions are you using?

"@azure/service-bus": "^7.9.5" This is the version of the relevant package. It is the newest one.

The reason why it fails to create subscription in Mozilla is because the Azure Service Bus SDK is not working as expected in this browser. Namely, this is the XML payload that is visible in Chromium based browsers:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <updated>2024-09-11T08:53:05.657Z</updated>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <SubscriptionDescription
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/netservices/2010/10/servicebus/connect"
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoDeleteOnIdle>PT1H</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
        </SubscriptionDescription>
    </content>
</entry>

And this is the one in Mozilla:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<entry>
    <updated>2024-08-28T09:36:15.430Z</updated>
    <content type="application/xml">
        <SubscriptionDescription
            xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <AutoDeleteOnIdle>PT1H</AutoDeleteOnIdle>
        </SubscriptionDescription>
    </content>
</entry>

So the attributes present in Chromium based browsers inside the entry tag do no texist in Mozilla and this is causing an error response.
Looks like it is related to this issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/11655
Also: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/30979
